# How to fix Acer Tab. Iconia one 7

Tags: applications

Hello can you help me fix my acer tab?

- I start to play a game then in the midway it force exits and prompted an error saying "Unfortunately [app] has stopped!"
- I noticed that the app icon in settings for example I will clear the cache of zombie tsunami so I will go in Settings then app then zombie tsunami the problem is the icon of zombie tsunami is replaced with android logo, can you help me?

Comment: does it happen with other applications/games ? it may be just this particular game is buggy. also, sometimes applications can behave strangely if you flash shady 3rd party roms.

Comment: I think thats not rooted and no custom roms installed.When I go in settings then app I saw the apps Icon when I tap it the Icon is android logo